# Position of player changes when the attack animation starts - unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sprite, pixel

So I did an attack animation in the program Aseprite and everything was fine with the animation, but when I put in inside the animator in unity the character changes position.
Here's the images, first one is a gif with the animation running as I want, and then the before and after of the animation in Unity.

[image]
I know it's small but I hope you can see
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because it's setting the center point at the location, and the gif is wider than the standard player image, you will need to offset to compensate.

Comment: Not sure if you said basically what I just put as a answer but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

So I just sliced the sprites again but with the pivot to the left instead of center, and then adjusted the Collider. It seems to work. Not sure if it's the perfect way though.